# Extracting information from an arraylist

Tags: java, apriori

I have an declared an `ArrayList a = [1,2,3]`. I created another `ArrayLList b` using the loop below:

```
for(int i = 0; i<a.size(); i++)
{
      for(int j=i+1; j<a.size();j++)
      {
              b.add("{" + a.get(i)+ "," + a.get(j) + "}");
      }
}
```

Now the `ArrayList` `b` will contain elements `[{1,2},{1,3},{2,3}]`. Now if I print the statement using `System.out.println(b.get(0))`, then the output will be `{1,2}`.

Now I want to to further explore the array such that I can extract `1` and `2` separately. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `System.out.println(a.get(0)), then the output will be {1,2}.` I do not get this part, it was a typo, and you would write `b.get(0)` ?

Comment: instead of declaring `ArrayList` b as a string type you can use array type.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create class pair

```
class Pair{
String a 
String b
....
///setters and getters
}
```

now let b will be `List<Pair>` so instead calling `b.add("{" + a.get(i)+ "," + a.get(j) + "}");` you can do simple `b.add(new Pair(a.get(i),a.get(j));`
then you don't need to play with splitting string and stuff like that, you can easly access your values by doing ie `b.get(0).getA()` or `b.get(0).get()`

you can also override method to string in pair

```
public String toString() {

    return "{" + a+ "," + b + "}";
}
```

so when you do `System.out.println(a.get(0))` you will get exactly same output like before

***EDIT
if you want to have a groups of more than 2 elements as you say in comment
you can construct your class little bit different

```
class MyClass{ 
List<Integer> fields = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//two constructors
MyClass(int singleVal)
{
fields.add(singleVal);
}


MyClass(MyClass a, MyClass b)
{
fields.addAll(a.fields);
fields.addAll(b.fields);
}
//getters setters depends what you need


}
```

both of your list will be list of MyClass, when you populate list a, you create objects by using first constructor, when you want to add elements to your b list you can do `b.add(new MyClass(a.(i),a.(j)))` but you can also do `b.add(new MyClass(a.(i),b.(j)))` or `b.add(new MyClass(b.(i),b.(j)))`

Comment: acutally its a great idea. But like i created element two set from 1-element set....i need to use that 2- element set to create 3-element set and from 3-element set to 4-element set as much as i can.  So, defining new strings in class pair will be tough. Is there any solution to it?

Comment: when i add it as you say....it gives as error that : "(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)"

Comment: that is strange, i just tried this code, i it is working fine for me, try to make class and constructors public, maybe this will help, if not tell me exactly what yo've done, so i tried to replicate this

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your array `b` holds just strings. Use any String tokenizing mechanism to achieve this - either [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) or [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Hint : StringTokenizer performs better

Comment: I am using it...but i m facing problems...will u please read the answer below who have given same reply as yours but there is problem in the code implementation

Answer (score 0):

You should decompose the presentation from logic.

In your loop you create a pair of element. So create a some type to represent it.

```
class Pair {

 private int left;
 private int right

 Pair(int left, int right) {
   this.left  = left;
   this.right = right;
 }

 public int getLeft() {
   return this.left;
 } 

 public int getRight() {
   return this.right;
 }

 @Override
 public void toString() {

     return String.format("{%d , %d}",getLeft(),getRight());
 }
}
```

List list = new ArrayList();

```
for(int i = 0; i<a.size(); i++)
{
      for(int j=i+1; j<a.size();j++)
      {
              list.add(new Pair(i,j));
      }
}
```

Then to access (extract) items

```
int l = list.get(0).getLeft();
int r = list.get(0).getRith();
```

If you want to display on console the result.

```
for(Pair p : list) {
  System.out.println(p);
}
```

[About output format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

---

**EDIT**

AS the OP mentioned in the comment. He would like to have flexible data structure that allow him to store the data.

```
List<List<Integer> parent = new ArrayList<List<Integer>()

for(int i = 0; i<a.size(); i++)
{

 List<Integer> child = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      for(int j=i+1; j<a.size();j++)
      {
              child.add(a.get(i));
              child.add(a.get(j));
      }

  parent.add(child);
}
```

Comment: but the problem is that i need to created 3-element sets from the two element set and from 3-elements set i need to create 4-element sets till it is possible. I like your style but how can i achieve this? I mean since i do not know how many k-element sets will be created, i cannot declare parameterised constructors in the class Pair. So, can you give me a good idea please?

Comment: There is none information in the question about set creation. So your problem  is that you have to create from k-element set a k+1-element set. This mean that your structure should be depend on any array or collection. So instead of having items left and right You create a list of lists.

Comment: I've edited the answer. But if that do not meet your expectation. You should create a new question with better example and scenario use case explanation.

Answer (score -1):

```
String ele = b.get(0);
ele = ele.replace("{", "");
ele = ele.replace("}", "");
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(ele, ",");
while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {

    int val = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. let me try it

Comment: The step two of above code does not work. It generates following error:                                                          incompatible types
  required: java.util.ArrayList
  found:    boolean

Comment: it generated Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,2" eroor

Comment: As the numbers are separated by commas, you will have to use comma as the delimiter in StringTokenizer. The default delimiter is semicolon. Update the answer again.

Comment: Thank you very much. The answer works!!! :) I will further study about StringTokenizer too. The answer is 1 2. Thanks!!!